# Compact $n$-manifold has same integral cohomology as $S^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $M$ be a compact connected $n$-manifold without boundary, where $n \ge 2$. Suppose that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Sigma Y$ for some connected based space $Y$. Does $M$ have the same integral homology as $S^n$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. First, recall that a suspension has no nontrivial cup products. By Poincaré duality, it follows that the integral cohomology of $M$ is torsion in degrees $1$ through $n-1$, and that the same is true of the integral homology. From universal coefficients we know that $H_{n-1}$ is torsion-free, which here implies that it's trivial. By Poincaré duality again, $H^1$ is trivial, so by universal coefficients again, $H_1$ is trivial, and by Poincaré duality again, $H^{n-1}$ is trivial. Now we can repeat the cycle: universal coefficients now implies that $H_{n-2}$ is trivial, etc.

Comment: Ah, here I've assumed that $M$ is orientable. My bad.

Comment: @Kevin: I was going to say this but was worried that I needed $Y$ to be path connected and afraid that $Y$ might be pathological. I'm happy to assume that $Y$ is a CW complex though, I guess.